# Show/hide password inside UpdatePanel asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I am trying to show/hide passwords inside an UpdatePanel in asp.net. I have assigned an to use an AsyncPostBackTrigger as:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkRegister" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
```

I have also used the UpdateMOde="Conditional" for the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelRegister" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

And finally, I have set the AutoPostBack="true" for the checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRegister" class="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkRegisterCheckedChanged"/>
```

The "chkRegisterCheckedChanged" call a JavaScript function to which I have checked and it is being called. The JS is to simply show or hide the text inside a password field:

```
function showPassword() {
var x = document.getElementById("txtPasswordReg");
if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
} else {
    x.type = "password";
}
```

}

The problem is that instead of showing the password, it is actually clearing the fields (perhaps a full post back?). 
Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="txtPasswordReg" type="password" value="testPassword">
<button onclick="ToggleShowPassword()">Toggle Password</button>
<script>
function ToggleShowPassword() {
    var x = document.getElementById("txtPasswordReg");
    if (x.type == "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}
</script>
```

This function does work. i'm not sure why you are having that issue

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KieranHolroyd/pevaj6zo/4/)

Comment: @Kieram, Yes, the JS works fine. It seems to be something with the asp UpadatePanel. Thanks for the response though. I appreciate.